# date of birth value doesn't show up in account information in admin panel on magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, date

I am trying to fetch the date of birth of end user but i show there no date of birth enter or saved in admin.

```
<div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('dob')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('dob')?>" />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you copy paste the code on getting the DOB?

Comment: hi @kiatng code is shown above in that I Did not get the dob value in controller

Comment: did you try with remove of style="display:none;" from div css

Comment: yes I remove then a blank area shown

Comment: What is `$this`, ie, the name of the block?

Comment: $this define its own class dob.phtml
@kiatng

Comment: `dob.phtml` is the name of the template, block name or type looks like this `core/template` or `Mage_Core_Block_Template`